# Alternate language versions of my website don't load when using a free hosting provider

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got my site (made with codeigniter) setup so that it loads alternate language versions of the pages when I put the language extension in the url like so:

```
domain/contact

domain/es/contact
```

The first one loads the default language version, and the one other should load the Spanish version.

It works just fine when I'm trying it on localhost, but when I try uploading it on a free hosting ([hostinger](http://www.hostinger.es/), not the final hosting I'm going to use) alternate language versions don't load (404 error).

What could possibly be the problem that **it works fine on localhost but not online?**

I've literally just jumped in on this project so I can't provide more info right now (as in, I *don't know* what info should I provide), but if you tell me what you need to know I can look it up in a moment.

Comment: Does the free hosting provider support PHP?  I wouldn't have thought so

Comment: The site works just fine in the default language, so I don't think that's the problem?

Comment: make sure all files have uploaded properly

Comment: maybe a `.htaccess` issue somewhere, try removing it

Comment: Does your host support mod_rewrite at all? Is it enabled ?

Comment: I just made sure that relevant files were indeed uploaded properly (they have). As for the .htaccess, I'm looking into it right now. mod_rewrite I don't know what is (as I said, I've just started on this project and the previous programmer can't be contacted).

Comment: I've just checked and mod_rewrite is indeed enabled.